# vue Typescript, Ref on object array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

[image]

I having problem how to properly declare object array into vue ref(). I came out with solution above, and I think is dumb. Please let me know any better ways to declare object array into vue ref. thanks man appreciate the helps.

Comment: share code as txt, not img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do it like this, instead you could simply declare your `postList` as

```
const postList = ref([] as Post[])
```

OR

```
const postList = ref<Post[]>([])
```

This will initialize an empty array to `postList` having the interface of `Post`